# Comparing elements of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large dataframe, called `recip`, where each row has format `recip1 recip2 num`. I want to trim it down by keeping only the rows where `recip1 < recip2`. Attached is an image of the first 10 rows of the dataframe. [image: Dataframe]

Note that `recip1` corresponds to `V1`, and `recip2` to `V2`. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: `recip[recip$recip1 < recip$recip2, ]`

Comment: Make sure that when you import your data you set `header = TRUE`. Your picture suggests that columns `V1` to `V3` are all characters or factors because of the entries in row 1.

Comment: based on your current structure you actually might need `df[as.numeric(as.character(df$recip1)) < as.numeric(as.character(df$recip2)), ]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use indexing for this

```
mtcars[ mtcars$drat > mtcars$wt , ]
```

here is the dplyr way

```
library( dplyr )
mtcars %>% filter( wt > drat )
```

Check your classes - you need numeric or integers for this

```
sapply( mtcars , class)
```